# Send argument with django redirect

Tags: django

I have a password check (not a user login, just a password verification). I have a form that user submits data. The request gets sent to a page, if the password is correct or not they both get back to the same page.

I want to send a argument to the page about the job. I was thinking of something like this: `foo.com/page?success`.

I can't get `shortcuts.redirect` to do that.

I am currently doing this:

```
HttpResponse('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace('+reverse('app:index')+');</script>')
```

Answer (score 1):

`redirect` redirects to whatever path you give it. If you give it `/page?success`, it will redirect to that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out nevermind

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:index')+'?arg')
```

This does it.